# How does the difference in length between two for loops affect performance?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

How does the difference in length between two for loops affect performance?
I know the performance is O(n) when using for loop. But how does the performance change as the length of the for loop changes? Does its complexity increase?

**Example a:**

```
for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
   do something...
}
```

**Example b:**

```
for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
   do something...
}
```

Comment: "I know the performance is O(n2) when using for loop" where do you get this idea from?

Comment: "Does its complexity increase?" No, complexity stays the same: complexity is how long it takes as the variable tends to infinity.

Comment: @AndyTurner i made a mistake. it would be O(n). I fixed it. Inner for loops are O(n2).

Comment: not even that is true. They can be pretty much any complexity, e.g. `for (int i = 1; i < N; i *= 2) {}` is `o(log N)`.

Comment: The complexity of both of your for loops is `O(1)` because both run a constant number of times regardless of the size of the input (if your program even has any input).

Comment: Err, have you researched this topic? What you are asking about should be explained in any good book about the subject like on page 1 or 2.

Comment: There is no `n` in any of the code here. It's all constant time. Loops have no inherent time complexity in and of themselves -- you have to analyze what they're _doing_ relative to `n`. If `n` doesn't exist as input to the function, it's nonsensical to say anything about `O(n)` of that function.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the for loop, it's how fast the variable is increasing or decreasing which will decide the loop complexity.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i*=2){
    do something;
}
```

this is O(logn)

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    do something;
    if(some condition)
          i = 0;
}
```

this might be O(n^2) [or even infinite loop] even though one loop.

Now if the length of the loop is a function of another dynamic variable yes performance is affected. If the length variation is constant then won't change.